# SQL joining with the same table

Tags: sql

I have a table with EVENT_ID column its have multiple entries against this event_id and then have event_name column.
 so my requirement is I need to select couple event-name along  with the finalized event records if the one of the event_name is finalized_Event and in the passed event_ids, otherwise ignore that event_id,  is there any way I can combine all query in one SQL.

```
       Select * from EVENT where EVENT_ID in ('0cbe3a81-8102-4eee-b8ef-07485f58cf0a','42b47725-4cc3-4620-9051-652d5409e69a','6e1b73d1-2f20-410c-80d2-89b0ccfde473')
   and 
    ( select * from EVENT where EVENT_NAME = 'FinalisedEvent' and (EVENT_NAME = 'CreatedEvent' or EVENT_NAME = 'DeletdEvent'))
```

Comment: Can you please share your current result and expected result?

Comment: can u share the table structure of event table, the sample expected output

Comment: EVENT_ID char(36) NOT NULL,
   EVENT_VER int NOT NULL,
   EVENT_SEQUENCE bigint NOT NULL,
   EVENT_NAME varchar(100),
   EVENT_DATA clob(1048576) NOT NULL,
   CREATE_TS timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL

Comment: I am not getting any data back with this SQL , there is one record in the database matching all this criteria

Comment: Obviously not if you're getting 0 rows back :). `EVENT_NAME = 'FinalisedEvent' and (EVENT_NAME = 'CreatedEvent' or EVENT_NAME = 'DeletdEvent')` - It's impossible for a field to have two values to match this condition. Where is the join mentioned in the question title? Please **edit the question** with new information, do not write comments.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like:

```
SELECT e1.* 
FROM EVENT e1
INNER JOIN EVENT e2
  ON e1.EVENT_ID = e2.EVENT_ID
  AND (e2.EVENT_NAME = 'CreatedEvent' OR e2.EVENT_NAME = 'DeletdEvent')
WHERE e1.EVENT_ID in ('0cbe3a81-8102-4eee-b8ef-07485f58cf0a','42b47725-4cc3-4620-9051-652d5409e69a','6e1b73d1-2f20-410c-80d2-89b0ccfde473')
AND e1.EVENT_NAME = 'FinalisedEvent'
```

Comment: Yes, but this join SQL not producing the expected result

Comment: I modified to this not sure about the correctness. SELECT e1.* 
FROM EVENT e1
INNER JOIN EVENT e2
  ON e1.EVENT_ID = e2.EVENT_ID
  AND (e2.EVENT_NAME = 'CreatedEvent' OR e2.EVENT_NAME = 'DeletdEvent' and e2.EVENT_NAME = 'FinalisedEvent')
WHERE e1.EVENT_ID in ('0cbe3a81-8102-4eee-b8ef-07485f58cf0a','42b47725-4cc3-4620-9051-652d5409e69a','6e1b73d1-2f20-410c-80d2-89b0ccfde473')